# JavaScript into StringBuilder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function in c # where I use StringBuilder and added JavaScript code, this is my helper:

```
public static string RegisterJS(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string scriptLib)
{
    StringBuilder JavaScript = new StringBuilder();
    JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"<script type= ""text/javascript"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"var toolbar = new toolBarObject('toolbarObj');{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"toolbar.disableElements('" + scriptLib + "', true);{0}", Environment.NewLine);
```

...
...
        JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"{0}", Environment.NewLine);
        return JavaScript.ToString();
    }

This function is called to load an application in Asp.Net MVC4 within a section:

as follows:

```
@section ToolBar{
  <h2>aqui debo cargar mi javascript</h2>
   @Html.RegisterJS("Personal")
}
```

I run the program and display the page code i have this:

```
&lt;script type= &quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
```

and I should have this:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
```

this happens in all lines of the function

how I can solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping this in  [`Html.Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.98).aspx)

```
@section ToolBar
{
 <h2>aqui debo cargar mi javascript</h2>
 @Html.Raw(Html.RegisterJS("Personal"))
}
```

Comment: @Lostdreamer - `Html.Raw` is handy :)

Comment: Yeah, you could also have the function to return HtmlString instead, razor wouldn't encode it this way.

Comment: @Lostdreamer - That is another valid approach, Raw simply returns an `HtmlString` instance. There are also ways of injecting the whole razor statement as well from a helper.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` symbol in razor syntax does HTML-encoding of the result.

You can prevent this by returning an `IHtmlString` from your method, which essentially communicates to the `@` symbol that your text does not need to be encoded.

The easiest way to do this would be to replace your last line with:

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(JavaScript.ToString());
```

Be careful of what you pass in, however!